# Align Items Flexbox , React Material in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, flexbox, material-design

I'm using flexbox, React Material in my React App and i wanted to align the searchbar and the clear button on the same line and with space on each other.

Pls see this link

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7di2c?file=/demo.js)

```
 <div className={classes.searchBarSection}>
      <Paper component="form" className={classes.searchBar}>
        <InputBase
          className={classes.input}
          placeholder="Search..."
          inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search..." }}
        />
        <IconButton
          type="button"
          className={classes.iconButton}
          aria-label="search"
        >
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Paper>
      <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="primary">
        Clear
      </Button>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you mean space around each other or between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  searchBarSection: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    width: "300px"
  },
```

adjust the width for how much space you want between them

this will look like:

[image]

Comment: Hi! You're here again :).  Can you put space on the searchbar and the clear button?

Comment: what do you mean by space in this regard?

Comment: @Robert have added an image to show you what mine looks like

Answer (score 0):

add these styles, the width will give the searchBatSection breathing room to space the children. Experiment around with the justifyContent options to find your suit.

```
  searchBarSection: {
    width: "50%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use grid

```
  searchBarSection: {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: '0.8fr 0.2fr',
    gap: '12px',
  },
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6w93i